# Creation of tag synonyms for Samsung Galaxy On7 tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Recently, while editing tag wikis for some new tags that I have added to the site, I found a tag [on7](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on7) as well as a tag [samsung-galaxy-on7](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-on7).

Needless to say, [on7](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on7) refers to nothing but [samsung-galaxy-on7](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-on7), as no other phone company has ever produced on7 model. I myself use the Galaxy on7, and there is no other model with only "on7".

It is useless to let [on7](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on7) exist as a tag by itself. Instead, itself think it should be made a **tag synonym** for [samsung-galaxy-on7](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-on7).

What are your views on this? I request the high reputation users and moderators to look into this.

Also, should we make a new tag [galaxy-on7](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/galaxy-on7) which will be again be a synonym to [samsung-galaxy-on7](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-on7)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good find. Merge completed. I don't think this needs a synonym (neither the old `on7` nor another `galaxy-on7`: if you type "galaxy-on7" in the tag box, `samsung-galaxy-on7` pops up automatically, same if you only type "on7".